# How to reset Flutter AnimatedGrid with new list of items?

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview, flutter-animatedlist

I am trying the [`widgets.AnimatedGrid.1 mysample`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedGrid-class.html#widgets.AnimatedGrid.1) of [AnimatedGrid class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedGrid-class.html) documentation and I am always getting a *RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range* whenever I replace at runtime the `late ListModel<int> _list` in `_AnimatedGridSampleState` with a new shorter list.

Simply replacing the code of `_insert` handler with:

```dart
void _insert() {
  setState(() {
    _list = ListModel<int>(
      listKey: _gridKey,
      initialItems: <int>[7, 6, 5],
      removedItemBuilder: _buildRemovedItem,
    );
  });
}
```

then clicking on `+` button will throw a `RangeError`.

Since `build()` in `AnimatedGridSampleState` depends of `_list` I was expecting that it will build a new `AnimatedGrid` with the correct `initialItemCount` and avoiding `RangeError`:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: ...,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: AnimatedGrid(
            key: _gridKey,
            initialItemCount: _list.length,
            itemBuilder: _buildItem,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Yet, the `_buildItem(...)` it is still being called with the same indexes of the former longer `_list`. Why?

---

You can try it by yourself running on the browser in the snippet container of [AnimatedGrid](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedGrid-class.html#widgets.AnimatedGrid.1) page, replacing `_insert()` code just like shown in the following print screens. You will not see the `RangeError` but you will see that former items 4, 5, 6 remain on the `AnimatedGrid`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you include full sample widget

Comment: The sample widget is in the AnimatedGrid documentation page here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedGrid-class.html#widgets.AnimatedGrid.1

Comment: I;ve replace the item with example code, but failed to reproduce the issue

Comment: You can try it on AnimatedGrid page in the code snippet and check a similar behaviour to the print screens that I included now in OP.

Answer (score 0):

To remove items takes `Duration(milliseconds: 300)`. So setState try to rebuild the items meanwhile and cause the issue. In order to overcome this issue, I came up with removing one by one and then inserting item, created another two method on the `ListModel`.

```dart
class ListModel<E> {
 .....
  void clear() {
    for (int i = _items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      removeAt(i);
    }
  }

  void addAll(List<E> item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      insert(i, item[i]);
    }
  }
```

Now while you like to reset the item.

```dart
  void _insert() async {
    _list.clear();
    /// delay to looks good; kDuration takes to remove item, therefore I am using Future method.
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    setState(() {
      _list.addAll(<int>[7, 6, 5]);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Although it is working, your proposal is a workaround and not a solution for reseting the list. Your proposal behaves with animation, removing all items and inserting new items. I would like to avoid animation and begin with a new grid with new items. Nevertheless, I think there is no need of `Future.delayed(...)`. I could use your proposal working with a simple non async `clear()` and without any delay, which can be called on demo `_insert()` as `void _insert() => setState(() { _list.clear(); _list.addAll(<int>[7, 6, 5]); });`. IMHO maybe you could fix your answer.

Comment: Actually I liked the animation while playing with it , feel free to adjust the changes you need.

Comment: Nevertheless the Future delay is useless. So it is not true that "_to overcome this issue I came up with waiting to finish_". You do not need `await` either.

Comment: Yes you are right, I might be too focused on animation

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by setting a new `GlobalKey<AnimatedGridState> _gridKey` on `_insert` handler of the OP example, which is now:

```dart
void _insert() {
    setState(() {
      _gridKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedGridState>();
      _list = ListModel<int>(
        listKey: _gridKey,
        initialItems: <int>[7, 6, 5],
        removedItemBuilder: _buildRemovedItem,
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. You update the key everytime you have a new data, which causes to lose the state of your widget. Instead of this, use: 

Single:
_gridKey.currentState?.insertItem(index);

Multiple:
_gridKey.currentState?.insertAllItems(index, newData.length);

Answer (score -1):

it would be better if you could share the function responsible for removing the item but i can guess what might be the problem if you are getting this error when removing the last item in the list

if you are removing an item then you need to be careful about something
first let's take a look at the removing function

```
E removeAt(int index) {
final E removedItem = _items.removeAt(index);
if (removedItem != null) {
  _animatedGrid!.removeItem(
    index,
    (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
      return removedItemBuilder(removedItem, context, animation);
    },
  );
}
return removedItem;
```

as you can see at the start of the function we are using the **index** to remove the item we want to remove and storing it in a new variable
then we are using it here

```
 _animatedGrid!.removeItem(
index,
(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
  return removedItemBuilder(removedItem, context, animation);
},);
```

as you can see we are using the item that we removed from the list because it will be displayed during the animation that's why we need the item but not the index
and we can't use the index directly in this part cause we already removed the item from the list so if we used it like that

```
 _animatedGrid!.removeItem(
    index,
    (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
      return removedItemBuilder(_items[index], context, animation);
    },
  );
```

you will be getting a RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range
because this item is already removed and so it's index is out of range